# How to delete an issue from SonarQube interface

Tags: sonarqube

I have a web app project where the quality is measured under sonarqube.

As i'm dealing with an external code within my project files

Recently i have had some issues appearing due to that exetrnal code and which i'm not focusing on its quality :

*So i wanna just delete the issue to appear from my sonar dashboard (which looks like the following):*

[image]

The solutions that i have had where not really usefull , as :

1. i was suggested to change the level of the rule itself from **"issue"** to **"info"** :
   [image]

And of course that seems to be not usefful because , i won't affect the rule itself

2. the second suggestion was to use the :

   `@SuppressWarnings` decorator in my blocks of code where the issues appeared ; : for example use it under *classes or methods or even fields*

**->** this method results in adding some code to my extarnal code and that won't be also good as i'm not even having the permission to do it.

I wanna just the **simpliest solution to delete the issue from the sonar dashboard** , just suppress it from the SonarQube interface , strangely it seems that there is no a direct way to do it :

**Any better ideas ??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is excluding external code from the report with [narrowing the focus feature](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus).

Just add to your `sonar-project.properties` file path pattern to exclusion, for example

> ```
> # Exclude all classes ending by "Bean"
> # Matches org/sonar.api/MyBean.java, org/sonar/util/MyOtherBean.java, org/sonar/util/MyDTO.java, etc.
> sonar.exclusions=**/*Bean.java,**/*DTO.java
>
> # Exclude all classes in the "src/main/java/org/sonar" directory
> # Matches src/main/java/org/sonar/MyClass.java, src/main/java/org/sonar/MyOtherClass.java
> # But does not match src/main/java/org/sonar/util/MyClassUtil.java
> sonar.exclusions=src/main/java/org/sonar/*
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not interested some issues because it's not your code, then you should not have SonarQube analyze that code. [According to the SonarQube documention](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus):

> We recommend that you exclude generated code, source code from
>   libraries, etc.

You should check in particular the following settings in the same documentation page:

- `sonar.sources`
- `sonar.exclusions`

These settings will be taken into account the next time you run an analysis.